# How to find the first duplicate in a Stream in scala

Tags: scala, stream

How to find the first duplicate in a Stream in scala ?

My current idea is to pair each element with a `Set` of all previous elements. Afterwards, `find` is called on the resulting `Stream`.

So, for each element, we have

- an insertion in a `Set` : O(1)
- a test `contains` in a `Set` : O(1)

Hence, the overall complexity of this algo seems O(n).

```
  def firstDuplicate[A](s: Stream[A]) = {
    def recurse(s: Stream[A], set: Set[A]) : Stream[(A, Set[A])]=
      (s.head, set) #:: recurse(s.tail, set + s.head)
    val pairedWithElements = recurse(s, Set.empty)
    pairedWithElements.find{ case (e, elems) => elems.contains(e)}.get._1
  }
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: How big do you expect the stream to be? And better, how various are the elements that can appear?

Comment: It seems to be fairly optimal approach, though for large or infinite streams it's going to use a lot of memory. You can try to experiment with Bloom filter instead of set, but you will need to go through previous n elements many times as it may return false positives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your function tail recursive. The way you have it, you are making pretty much another copy of your whole stream on the stack. Also, I don't understand why you are making a copy of the entire stream (and a whoooole buuunch of sets), and then scanning it again to find the dup. You can tell it's a dup right away, when adding it to the set, and stop right there.

Something like this perhaps:

```
   def firstDup[T](s: Stream[T], seen: Set[T] = Set.empty[T]): Option[T] =  s match {
      case head #:: tail if seen(head) => Some(head)
      case head #:: tail => firstDup(tail, seen + head)
      case _ => None
   }
```

The bloom filter suggestion from the comments above is a good idea for *truly huge* input streams. The "outer shell" would stay the same in that case, you'd just need to change the underlying `seen` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your much simpler solution. Just 2 typos : s/#:/#:: and s/empty/empty[T]

Comment: The first one was a typo (fixed now). The other one is not - the type param is unnecessary there, it can be inferred.

Comment: Without the type parameter, I encounter this compilation error when I call the method : [error] Note: Nothing <: Pos, but trait Set is invariant in type A.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Pos`. (SLS 3.2.10)

Comment: Hm, you are right ... Didn't occur to me to actually call it ... 
The weird thing is that `firstDup(Seq(1,2,3,4,2).toStream, Set.empty)` actually works. Oh well ...